# Regex: Get separate parameters and parameter type of the CPP function (c#)

Tags: c#, c++, regex

I do not know much regex, how to get the type of a variable and a variable?

Example source text:

```
func (int arg1, float *arg2, float *arg3)
func2 (const char * name, int arg1, int arg2, int arg3, void * mem)
```

Example regex

```
(\\(.*?)\\)
```

— all variables at once, but how to get them separately?

```
\\((.*?),(.*?),(.*?)\\)
```

`int arg1` `float *arg2` `float *arg3`, but may be more than 3 options ... And I need to get the type and parameter separately.

Comment: C and C++ grammar are much more complicated than could be parsed with a regular expression. Consider: `void f(void (*g)(int, int))` (a function that takes a pointer to function as a parameter).

Comment: Why not grab all the variables like you're already doing it and split on the comma later?

Comment: I always have "float *name" "int name" "void * name" etc

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you insist in using regex and assuming your function signatures aren't getting very complicated, then you could looping against all var_type var pairs, like the following
`while(s/(.*?) (\S+),//)`

Answer (score 0):

You should get yourself a copy of Antlr:

http://www.antlr.org/

If you've trying to parse C/C++ header files, there's more to it than just function declarations. Especially if it's C++.

Antlr is a great too for doing the sort of partial parse and tranformations that you seem to be talking about. Besides that, you get a [C grammar](https://github.com/antlr/grammars-v4/commit/15df18159653f7ae2963cc73bec7d2b8939a9363) for free, which *might* be sufficient for your needs (but I wouldn't count on it).

Get Terrance Parr's books, too:

- [The Definitive ANTLR 4 Reference](http://pragprog.com/book/tpantlr2/the-definitive-antlr-4-reference)
- [Language Implementation Patterns: Create Your Own Domain-Specific and General Programming Languages](http://pragprog.com/book/tpdsl/language-implementation-patterns)